# Material-UI - Tooltip on Select/MenuItem component stays displayed after selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI's Select component with a Tooltip surrounding it, like so:

```
<Tooltip title="Tooltip Test">
  <Select value={this.state.age} onChange={this.handleChange}
    inputProps={{ name: "age", id: "age-simple" }}
  >
    <MenuItem value="">
      <em>None</em>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>...</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</Tooltip>
```

My problem is that when I click the Select component, the Tooltip stays displayed, during the use of the Select, and even after an item was selected.

I want it to disappear as soon as the Select is clicked so that it doesn't stay over the MenuItems (Changing the zIndex is not the solution I want) and also still is not displayed even after selecting an item in the menu.

I made a codesandbox with the simple issue I have: https://codesandbox.io/s/yvloqr5qoj

But I am using typescript and this is the actual code I'm working with:

#### ControlledTooltip

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import withStyles, { WithStyles } from 'material-ui/styles/withStyles';
import { Tooltip } from 'material-ui';

const styles = {

}

type State = {
    open: boolean,
};

type Props = {
    id: string,
    msg: string,
    children: PropTypes.node,
};


class ControlledTooltip extends React.PureComponent<Props & WithStyles<keyof typeof styles>, State> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: false,
        };
    }

    private handleTooltipClose(): void {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    }

    private handleTooltipOpen(): void {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    }

    render() {
        const { id, msg, children } = this.props;
        const { open } = this.state;

        return(
            <div>
                <Tooltip id={id}
                    title={msg}
                    open={open}
                    onClose={this.handleTooltipClose}
                    onOpen={this.handleTooltipOpen}
                >
                    {children ? children : null}
                </Tooltip>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ControlledTooltip);
```

#### Component using the Tooltip

```
<ControlledTooltip msg={'Filter'}>
    <Select value={this.state.type} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, Filter.Type)}>
        {this.docTypeFilters.map(item => {
            return (<MenuItem key={item} value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>);
        })}
    </Select>
</ControlledTooltip>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You have to make your tooltip [controlled](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tooltips/).

**UPDATE:**
Based on your actual code, replace the return of your `render()` with this:

```
            <Tooltip id={id}
                title={msg}
                open={open}
            >
                <div onMouseEnter={this.handleTooltipOpen}
                     onMouseLeave={this.handleTooltipClose}
                     onClick={this.handleTooltipClose}
                >
                   {children ? children : null}
                </div>
            </Tooltip>
```

The problem was that you were using onClose/onOpen from the tooltip, which works as is uncontrolled. Now the `div` containing the select(or any children) has the control over the tooltip.

**ANSWER FOR THE PASTEBINS**

You will need to handle the open prop of the Tooltip:

```
class SimpleSelect ... 
    constructor(...
        state = {..., open: false}; // the variable to control the tooltip
```

Alter your change handling:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value, open: false });// keeps the tooltip hidding on the select changes
};

handleOpen = (open) => {
    this.setState({ open }); // will show/hide tooltip when called
}
```

And reflect it in your `render()`:

```
 const { open } = this.state; // obtains the current value for the tooltip prop
 ...
 <Tooltip title="Tooltip Test" open={open}>
 ...
   <Select ... onMouseEnter={() => this.handleOpen(true)}
               onMouseLeave={() => this.handleOpen(false)}
               onClick={() => this.handleOpen(false)} >
```

The event handlers(onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, onClick) in Select now control the tooltip show/hide behavior.

Comment: What if I want to have multiple select components and want the tooltip to be in a separated component? (I changed my question a bit for more context)

Comment: Also, I am wondering what's the use of selectOpen? By the way thanks for the good reply!

Comment: selectOpen is an upsy =]. If the tooltip is controlled you can put it anywhere, but it will use that component (your separated component) as an anchor to position itself.  handleOpen is now controlling when to show/hide it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to change the state of a component X when component Y is being clicked :s

Comment: Oh, I see. This is more a React question, you may want to ask that question separately for more details. In this scenario, Tooltip (Component X) has its inner state "open", which you can change via props.  Now, ControlledTooltip (Component Y), passes its state "open" to the Tooltip prop "open", thus controlling Tooltip. Finally, ControlledTooltip delegates its "open" state changes to the Select component via props: onClick={() => this.handleOpen(false)}. (the answer will have this comments as well)

Comment: Let me know if the changes worked. I have no TS environment to test it with.

Comment: That was it, the div handling the events inside the tooltip/around the children elements. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Same as David's answer, but for functional components with React [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

In your component before the return:

```
const [tooltipOpen, setTooltipOpen] = useState(false)
const handleTooltip = bool => {
    setTooltipOpen(bool)
}
```

Then in your return:

```
<Tooltip ... open={tooltipOpen}>
    <Select
        onMouseEnter={() => {handleTooltip(true)}}
        onMouseLeave={() => {handleTooltip(false)}}
        onMouseClick={() => {handleTooltip(false)}}
        ...
    >
```

Comment: In new versions of material-ui (e.g. 4.9.x), I get an error that the prop onMouseClick does not exist. I used onOpen instead.

Comment: Adding this code (with @Markus suggestion) forces the tooltip away when clicking on the `<Select>` but now the default behavior of the `<Select>` goes away (that is, it will no longer open). Any ideas why this might be?